# How to update a value of _Layout from its PartialView in ASP.NET MVC 'Razor'?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been looking for the solution and I haven't find a way to get my head around it. So I hope you could give me some clues to achieve that.

Basically I need to change a value of a _Layout from its rendered PartialView. I use to do this using webforms .aspx master pages and FindControl method but I cannot find a solution to do this in MVC **Razor** engine.

My Layout page has an ActionLink and a `div` tag place-holder to display the partial-views, Now I need to know how to change the value of Text1 from the partial-view pages within the DIV tag:

**Is JavaScript the only way that I can do this ?**

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" />
<div>
   @Ajax.ActionLink("Personal Info", "Personal", "Portal", new { area = "Resume" },
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", HttpMethod = "Post", 
                          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                          OnBegin = "blockUi", 
                          OnSuccess = "onTabChanged(this, 'Personal Information')" 
                        }, 
        new { @class = "text-strong" })
</div>
<div id="result">@RenderBody()</div>
```

Appreciate your contributions in advance.

Comment: you have to do it via jquery

Comment: Thanks for the clue, do you think that is the only way I could do this though ?

Comment: in mvc you have to stick iwth jquery or make container div in master layout and load partial view there

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is the way this is handled I think.

You might be able to do some trickery with controllers and the ViewBag (like how the page title is set with the ViewBag in a default MVC project).

You could also maybe set it to some global variable or something, and have your partial view change that variable.

Both those solutions though would require a page reload.

But using javascript is probably the best, you could do it in the `onTabChanged` function.

```
<script>
    function onTabChanged(param1, param2) {
        var el = document.getElementById("Text1");
        el.value = "Whatever you want here";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is using a ViewBag that you play around with in your controller/view/partial view.

Answer (score 0):

In WebForms you can use the FindControl method because a PostBack was made. So the entire page was rendered again.

In the example you posted, I assumed that the request made by Ajax.ActionLink that update the div result, returns a view that may use the same Layout, but is in another context so you don't have access to the same input text from the rendered page where Ajax.Action link was triggered.

So, if you have multiples Ajax.ActionLink that updates the `<div id="result">`, you need to handle the success method on onTabChanged, like @Kyle Gobel suggested.